# Firestore Rule on Sub Collection

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am having a members sub collection under a branch collection. My firestore rules always fail when i try to get the members from the subcolection of a branch. Rules playground works but the actual app code always get:

> FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Below is the rule. I think the problem is that i am unable to access `resource.data.company_id`. Whereas the rules work if i do return userId != null.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{path=**}/members/{member} {
      function isCompanyAdmin(companyId, userId) {
        return companyId != null; //THIS DOESN'T WORK
        //return userId != null; //THIS WORKS
      }
      allow read: if request.auth != null && isCompanyAdmin(resource.data.company_id, request.auth.uid);
    }
  }
```

js:

```
const branchRef = doc(db, "branch", branch_id);
const memberRef = collection(branchRef, "members");
const q = query(memberRef);
const querySnapShot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapShot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to your query so that it only returns document with a field `companyId`. An `orderBy(companyId)` should also do the trick.

Explanation: [Rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters)

Comment: Adding companyID to the query works. I am trying to understand this. Why does the query need to have a field in order to access that field on the rule? Wouldn't i be able to access all fields from a document in the rule irrespective of whether the field is present in the query?

Comment: I added a link explaining this. Please accep the answer if it solves your problem